# Issue with the templatized version of insertion sort

Tags: sorting, c++11, move-semantics

Below is the templatized version of insertion sort which results in compilation errors to perform insertion sort in place without any extra space.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
insertSort(T start, T end)
{
    typename std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type> TmpVec;
    TmpVec tmp(std::make_move_iterator(start), std::make_move_iterator(end));
    TmpVec::iterator begin = std::begin(tmp);
    TmpVec::iterator end = std::end(tmp);
    for(TmpVec::iterator i = begin; i != end; i++)
    {
        typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type value = *i;
        TmpVec::iterator pos = i;
        while (pos > start && *(pos-1) > value)
        {
            *pos = std::move(*(pos-1));
            --pos;
        }
        *pos = value;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::vector<double> arr = {1,5,3,2,6,3,9,8};
    insertSort<double>(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling this with the following compilation line.

```
g++ -std=c++11   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
```

This yields the following errors.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int insertSort(T, T)':
main.cpp:21:12: error: expected ';' before 'tmp'
     TmpVec tmp(std::make_move_iterator(start), std::make_move_iterator(end));
            ^
main.cpp:22:5: error: 'TmpVec' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
     TmpVec::iterator begin = std::begin(tmp);
     ^
main.cpp:23:5: error: 'TmpVec' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
     TmpVec::iterator end = std::end(tmp);
     ^
main.cpp:24:9: error: 'TmpVec' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
     for(TmpVec::iterator i = begin; i != end; i++)
         ^
main.cpp:24:37: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
     for(TmpVec::iterator i = begin; i != end; i++)
                                     ^
main.cpp:27:9: error: 'TmpVec' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
         TmpVec::iterator pos = i;
         ^
main.cpp:28:16: error: 'pos' was not declared in this scope
         while (pos > start && *(pos-1) > value)
                ^
main.cpp:33:10: error: 'pos' was not declared in this scope
         *pos = value;
          ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:40:46: error: no matching function for call to 'insertSort(std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator)'
     insertSort<double>(arr.begin(), arr.end());
                                              ^
main.cpp:40:46: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:18:1: note: template<class T> int insertSort(T, T)
 insertSort(T start, T end)
 ^
main.cpp:18:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:40:46: note:   cannot convert 'arr.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<double, std::allocator<double> >()' (type 'std::vector<double>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >}') to type 'double'
     insertSort<double>(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

Kindly help in solving the above issue.

Comment: `TmpVec` is declared a variable. Did you forget `typedef`? Once that's fixed, everywhere you have `TmpVec::iterator`, make it `typename TmpVec::iterator` (or add another typedef).

Comment: `insertSort<double>` takes two parameters of type `double`, not `vector<double>::iterator`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Or, you know, `auto` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
typename std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type> TmpVec;
```

this states `std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>` is a typename.  A compiler should issue a warning/error, because the `typename` is redundant.

It then declares a variable `TmpVec` of that type.

Every use after that uses `TmpVec` as if it was a type, not a variable.

You probably want

```
typedef std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type> TmpVec;
```

I'd also advise

```
using tmp_iterator = typename TmpVec::iterator;
```

and using `tmp_iterator` as a type instead of `TmpVec::iterator`.

Comment: That `typename`'s redundant but allowed (of course, later use shows that it probably wasn't intended). `typename std::template vector<int>` FTW :)